# Including tokenfield package to laravel with npm

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, npm

Im trying to include tokenfield package with npm to laravel.

First i added following line to package.json dependencies:

```
"tokenfield": "^0.8.2",
```

This resulted in tokenfield folder under node-models.
Then i added following lines to webpack.mix.js:

```
.copy('node_modules/tokenfield/dist/tokenfield.js', 'public/js')
.copy('node_modules/tokenfield/dist/tokenfield.css', 'public/css')
```

This resulted in me having tokenfield javascript and css in my public folder. Now i just include those in my view like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/tokenfield.js') }}"></script>
```

But this doesent work. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at tokenfield.js:1
```

When i look at the tokenfield.js it doesent look like a regular javascript file, it starts with:

```
module.exports =
```

So what am i doing missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you need to transpile NPM packages. Do this:

In your main js (e.g. app.js)

```
window.Tokenfield =  require("tokenfield");
```

`window` needs to be used in order to make it globally acessible because transpiled dependencies are all executed within an [iife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and is therefore not part of the global scope by default (this is not necessary for all modules).

In your main SCSS (e.g. app.scss)

```
@import "node_modules/tokenfield/lib/scss/tokenfield"
```

Then it should work with the default mix boilerplate.

Comment: What do you mean by default mix boilerplate? I dont quite understand where do i have to copy the tokenfield dist for thoses references to work? At the moment i get the following error: File to import not found or unreadable: tokenfield.

Comment: Laravel ships with [this JS](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js) and [this scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/sass/app.scss) file used by the default [webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js) file (the idea is the same for versions of Laravel before 5.4 but gulp is used instead of webpack.mix. The idea here is to basically require the library. That way webpack will know to include it in your compiled assets.

Comment: So i got the css working by using: @import "node_modules/tokenfield/lib/scss/tokenfield"; But there is still a problem with javascript. If i just add require("tokenfield"); to my app.js then i can see that my compiled app.js has some tokenfield related functions added, but when i try to use the tokenfield then i get the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Tokenfield is not defined". If i just include this script instead "https://github.com/KaneCohen/tokenfield/blob/master/dist/tokenfield.min.js" everything works fine. Any ideas what could be the problem when inculding through app.js?

Comment: @user1985273 scripts included via `require` and then packed are in the form of an [iife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so they are not in the window scope, you can do `window.Tokenfield = require("tokenfield")` to make the `Tokenfield` lib available globally.